# Unwanted padding appears in WebView when layout_height="wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-webview, android-coordinatorlayout

I used to have a `WebView` filling the entire screen (using `"match_parent"` for both `layout_width` and `Layout_height`) so that content was scrolled inside a webview.

Now I want to use `CoordinatorLayout` with `NestedScrollView` to make a fancy collapsing toolbar. I put the `WebView` inside `NestedScrollView` so it took over the scrolling functionality. I'm generally fine with downsides of this but it also made the `WebView` "infinitely" high. To avoid that I changed `layout_height` of `WebView` to `wrap_content`. It solved the scrolling issue but created another: now mysteriously the HTML content has additional padding on each edge that cannot be removed with CSS. I also tried switching use of wide viewport on and off with no result.

Here is how it looks like (i added some backgrounds and borders to show what is what)

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: blue;
    color: #eee;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: green;
}

#content {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 12px 12px 36px 12px;
}
```

[image: WebView with unwanted padding]

So simply speaking - how to get rid of blue and green paddings without going back to `match_parent`?

Comment: Can't you listen to the touch gesture on webview and collapse/expand toolbar?

Comment: Tried. This solution was causing flickering on older(?)/some devices. Basically - it's hard to implement it reliably while CoordinatorLayout provides a robust implementation out of the box.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to collapse completely in one go.... Coordinatorlayout plays well only with scroll/listview as far as i know.